# Angular CLI Passing Environment Variable in command

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Is there any way to pass some parameters when using angular cli command like `ng build` or especially in my case `ng serve` to change or set variables in environment without changing environment file or define new environment each time?

For example I have this environment.ts file

```
    export const environment = {
     apiData: true,
     authentication: true,
     checkValidation: true,
     signData: false,
     mockFileDirectoryUrl: '/assets/',
     saveUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/'
     getUrl: 'http://localhost:5005/'
    };
```

And I want to run my app in local for test with `signData=true` flag and different `SaveUrl` with a command like:`ng serve signData true saveUrl "https:/localhost:5050"`

I have found this approach [How to pass environment variables at building time in an Angular application using .env files](https://medium.com/@ferie/how-to-pass-environment-variables-at-building-time-in-an-angular-application-using-env-files-4ae1a80383c) but the problem is  with this solution each time the environment file is completely rewrote but I want pass these variables just in runtime.

Comment: You can create separate environment files for normal serve and for prod mode `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` respectively, this will be an easier method if you have many variables to pass.

Comment: @BINFASK I have separate environment for production but on local I have many flags on my environment which I want to change some of them under some circumstances otherwise I should change the environment each time.

Comment: Does this https://medium.com/@ferie/how-to-pass-environment-variables-at-building-time-in-an-angular-application-using-env-files-4ae1a80383c help?

Comment: @huanfeng Thank you but I have linked to this approach in my question and I have explain why this can't help me

Comment: This could help you https://medium.com/@balramchavan/configure-and-build-angular-application-for-different-environments-7e94a3c0af23

Comment: @BINFASK Thank you but this is my current way for setting different environment but with this solution I should have too many custom environment.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [@ngx-env/builder](https://github.com/chihab/ngx-env), it exposes environment variables like these:

```bash
NG_APP_ENABLE_ANALYTICS=false
NG_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
NG_APP_COMMIT=$GITHUB_SHA
```

as global variables:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: "app-footer",
})
export class FooterComponent {
  version = process.env.NG_APP_VERSION;
  branch = process.env.NG_APP_BRANCH_NAME;
  commit = process.env.NG_APP_COMMIT;
  analyticsFlag = process.env.NG_APP_ENABLE_ANALYTICS;
}
```

and via a pipe:

```html
<!-- Same output in the spans -->
<span> {{ 'process.env.NG_APP_BRANCH_NAME' | env }} </span>
<span> {{ 'NG_APP_BRANCH_NAME' | env }} </span>
<span> {{ branch }} </span>
```

Examples courtesy of the project readme.