# How can I change an environment variable at build time?

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables, command-line-interface, build-time

I have the following *environment.ts* file:

```
export const environment = {
    serverUrl: 'anything',
};
```

I often need to change this serverUrl, so I want to change this property by CLI, for example:
`ng build --configuration=production serverUrl:'http://whatever'`.
**I don't want to create one environment to each server**

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029835/angular-cli-passing-environment-variable-in-command) which say to use the [@ngx-env/builder](https://github.com/chihab/ngx-env).
Then, I've installed the package and changed my *env.d.ts* file:

```
interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly NG_SERVER_URL: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

But when I tried to run the command: `NG_SERVER_URL=anything ng build --configuration` I received the classic error:

> The term 'NG_SERVER_URL=anything' is not recognized as the name of an operable cmdlet, function, script file, or program.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another approach to change this URL at build time?

Comment: the error message makes me wonder if you are using windows? i guess passing ENV variables in windows (power?)shell works differently.

Comment: I recommend using a separate file for the env-vars. Here is a tutorial for it:
https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/angular-build-once-deploy-to-multiple-environments#wrapping-up